# Proving a problem as NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, np

According to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/np-completeness-set-1/) article, 
A problem X can be proved to be NP-complete if an already existing NP-complete problem (say Y) can be polynomial-time reduced to current problem X. The problem also needs to be NP. Now my question is:

> Do we also need to prove that problem X can be reduced to at least one
>   NP problem?

According to the definition of NP-completeness, each and every NP 
problem must be reducible to NP-complete problem. As problem X is NP, are we not supposed to prove that this NP problem can be reduced to other NP-complete problems? Why does this reduction have to be only one way to prove a problem is NP-complete?
[image: Image describing the problem visually]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have stated, there are two very clear requirements for a problem $X$ to be $\mathbf{NP}$-complete:

1. $X \in \mathbf{NP}$.
2. $X$ is $\mathbf{NP}$-hard. That is, for every $Y \in \mathbf{NP}$, $Y$ is (poly-time many-one) reducible to $X$.

> Do we also need to prove that problem $X$ can be reduced to at least one $\mathbf{NP}$ problem?

No, as this is not one of the above requirements. However, if you are able to do so, you've proved that $X \in \mathbf{NP}$ (i.e., requirement no. 1): Suppose $X$ is reducible to $Y \in \mathbf{NP}$. Then verifying $x \in X$ can be done in poly-time by reducing $x$ to an instance $y$ of $Y$ and then verifying $y \in Y$.

> As problem $X$ is $\mathbf{NP}$, are we not supposed to prove that this $\mathbf{NP}$ problem can be reduced to other $\mathbf{NP}$-complete problems?

There is no need to. If you know $Y$ is $\mathbf{NP}$-complete and you show $X \in \mathbf{NP}$, then necessarily $X$ is reducible to $Y$. There is no need for you to do "extra" work.

> Why does this reduction have to be only one way to prove a problem is $\mathbf{NP}$-complete?

I am afraid I am not quite sure which reduction you are referring to, but if you are talking about reducing $X$ to $Y$, then the answer is simply: That is what the definition of $\mathbf{NP}$-completeness requires you to do.

Comment: Pease check the image that I have attached to the question. I still don't understand how X is reducible to Y.

Comment: @SaiCharan What is missing in your picture is an arrow from x to y in the second diagram. You have established x is in NP, so it is reducible to y for the exact same reason a, b, and c are.

Comment: I still don't get it. a,b,c were reducible to y because they were proved explicitly. Does this mean I also need to prove that x is reducible to y?

Comment: If you've proved only a, b, and c are reducible to y, then *you've done something wrong*. There are infinitely many problems in NP, so you can't just reduce them one by one to y. Also, if y is NP-complete, then *any* problem in NP is reducible to it, whether you're aware of its existence or not!

Answer (score 1):

> Do we also need to prove that problem X can be reduced to at least one NP problem?

No. Every problem in **NP** can be reduced to some problem in **NP**: namely, to itself. "Can be reduced to at least one **NP** problem" isn't a part of the definition of **NP**-completeness, so you don't need to prove it.  You just need to prove the things required by the definition.

Comment: Please check the image that I have attached to the question. I don't think my doubt was clear to everyone.

Comment: The definition of $L$ being **NP** complete is that (1) $L$ is in **NP** and (2) every problem in **NP** reduces to $L$. To prove that something is **NP**-complete, you need to prove (1) and (2) _and nothing else_.